# Crashed: MRAVConcreteRoutingDiscoverySession

Tags: ios11.2

Recently, our app collected many of these crashes through the fabric (most of them crashed on 11.2

Crashed: MRAVConcreteRoutingDiscoverySession
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000004d407bec8

Comment: Did you find any solution?